# Google Oauth2 redirect_uri_mismatch for PHP Web Application Using HybridAuth

Tags: php, yii, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm using Google OAuth2 for login on yii framework using hybridauth module.

I've setup the API in the google developer console,
https://console.developers.google.com

But I'm getting the redirect_mismatch_uri error.

I'm testing it on localhost. I've given this in redirect uri,

```
http://localhost:90/TestApp/index.php
```

Is there any wrong i'm doing here ?

Please,suggest.

Thanks,
Faisal Nasir

Answer (score 0):

It does not work on local server. You must check it on host server. And check your API **Redirect URIs** is equels with your relar **callback url**. If you don't know `callback url` than open browser console and find request url. Usealy it will be after `&redirect_uri=` (To be hones, In my case I solve the problem like that)